# EJS Django implementation

Tags: django, ejs

Let's say I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ejs_production.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    data = {
        title: "My title",
        names: 
            ['myname1', 'myname2', 'myname3']

    }

    var html = new EJS({
        element: document.getElementById('template')
    }).render(data);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="template">
        <h1><%= title %></h1>
        <ul>
            <% for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++) { %>
                <li>
                    <a href='supplies/<%= names[i] %>'>
                        <%= names[i] %>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Can anyone tell me why my template is not rendering? This is a basic template example that I want to test in order to integrate EJS with Django.

What I want is the following:
I get some JSON data, then I have a div with a complex structure in which I have EJS vars. I want to be able to populate my element with the JSON data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have several issues:

1. At the time document.getElementById('template') is called, div#template doesn't exist

2. You don't want a search engine bot to find broken HTML like this: <h1><%= title %></h1>

Comment: I've wrapped my code in window.onload = function(){{ and my template is still not rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Put your second javascript block before the `</body>` tag.